# Apple II - How to concatenate basic program lines together on a single line to reduce the program's size/line count

Tags: retro-computing, apple-ii

Apple ][ - What the command used to squeeze an Apple basic program so that it puts as many lines of Basic code on a single line as possible?  **This is for the program's code and not for an input or output text file.**

This was done to make the programs take up less memory and run faster.

```
100 PRINT "First print statement"
110 PRINT "Second print statement"
110 GOTO 200
120 PRINT "Third print statement"
130 GOTO 300
200 PRINT "Fourth print statement"
300 PRINT "Fifth print statement"
```

Would be changed to the following by adding ":" characters between lines

```
100 PRINT "First print statement" : PRINT "Second print statement" : GOTO 200
120 PRINT "Third print statement" : GOTO 300
200 PRINT "Fourth print statement"
300 PRINT "Fifth print statement"
```

There were commands to compact a Basic program and uncompact it this way.

Comment: There were no built-in commands to do this. You had to buy a separate utility.

Comment: @RaymondChen Do you know of the utility program name?

Comment: I don't remember.